# What is $\left | \left | A \right | \right |$ equals to in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Can someone please tell me what is this $\left | \left | A \right | \right |$ equals to? (determinant inside determinant)

Comment: This is the notation for the matrix norm $|| \cdot ||$...

Comment: It depends on context. It's almost certainly not a determinant inside a determinant. Sometimes this is just a notation for a matrix $A$. Other times it could be the norm of a matrix, whose specific definition will vary from case to case.

Comment: This is a norm of (most often) a matrix $A$.

Comment: @adjan I when I wrote this question I ment determinant inside determinant :)

Comment: @david when I wrote this question I ment determinant inside determinant :)

Comment: @svetoslav when I wrote this question I ment determinant inside determinant :)

Comment: Um, what are you trying to say with your comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$||A||$ in a sense of $\det(\det( A))$ makes absolutely no sense.  Even if you define $\det(A) := (\det (A))$, i.e. as a $1\times 1$-matrix, $\det (\det A)$ would be just $\det (A)$...

The determinant is a **scalar**.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, in linear algebra (and functional analysis, and many other fields) double vertical lines $\|\cdot\|$ denote a norm. If $A:V\to W$ is a linear operator between normed vector spaces (or a matrix in the finite-dimensional case with a fixed choice of basis), then often the following norm is used
$$\|A\| = \sup_{x\in V}\frac{\|Av\|_W}{\|v\|_V},$$
where $\|\cdot\|_V$ is the norm on $V$, and similarly for $W$.

Comment: Which is also equal to $$\sup_{x \in S} ||Av||_W$$, with $S$ the unit sphere of $V$ (may be easier to understand this way)

Comment: when I wrote this question I ment determinant inside determinant :)